# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error when compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Very simply, I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Tetris::rotate(int (*) [2], int)", referenced from:
      Tetris::add_piece(char, int, int) in tetris-8a8072.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is my rotate function:

```
int** rotate(int oldpiece[][2],int rot){
    int **newpiece= new int*[4];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        newpiece[i] = new int[2];
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<2; ++j){
            newpiece[i][j]=oldpiece[i][j];
        }
    }
    return newpiece;
}
```

old piece is an 4x2 array of ints.

As of now all this function should do is copy `oldpiece` into `newpiece` and then `return newpiece;`. I have no idea what this error means.

Comment: When you have linker errors, it's always better to see whole thing by giving -v (as suggested in the error message) for verbose output.

Comment: Is that definition inside the `Tetris` class/namespace? If not, you need to qualify the name, `Tetris::rotate`, otherwise you're declaring a new, unrelated function.

Comment: as of right now i am including `<iostream>`, `<string.h>`, and `"tetris.h`. Is there something else i should be including?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external library? if so, you must link it.
Also, try compiling the program under release option instead of debug option.